# NetworkX DiGraphMatcher returns no results on directed graphs?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

I have a large graph in which I want to find a subgraph isomorphism using the built-in VF2 algorithm in NetworkX. Both the 'haystack' as well as 'needle' graphs are directed. Take the following trivial example:

```py
from networkx.algorithms.isomorphism import DiGraphMatcher

G1 = nx.complete_graph(20, nx.DiGraph)

G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_edge(1, 2)

list(DiGraphMatcher(G1, G2).subgraph_isomorphisms_iter())
```

The final line returns an empty list `[]`.

My understanding is that this should return all edges in the graph, and indeed, if I substitute `GraphMatcher` for `DiGraphMatcher`, I get a list of all edges.

Is there something wrong with `DiGraphMatcher`, or perhaps something wrong with my understanding of what `DiGraphMatcher` should be doing?

**Versions:**

- Python: 3.7.7
- NetworkX: 2.4

---

Example undirected graph code (replaces all `DiGraph` with `Graph`, otherwise the same):

```py
from networkx.algorithms.isomorphism import GraphMatcher

G1 = nx.complete_graph(20, nx.Graph)

G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_edge(1, 2)

list(GraphMatcher(G1, G2).subgraph_isomorphisms_iter())
```

Comment: On your sample, both `DiGraphMatcher` and `GraphMatcher` return empty list on my computer.

Comment: @AndyL. just added undirected-graph example code, thank you for checking this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question after many hours of sorrow. I was hoping this was going to be an interesting technical question. Turns out it's just a run-of-the-mill nomenclature question!

NetworkX defines a subgraph isomorphism as the following:

> If G'=(N',E') is a node-induced subgraph, then:
>
> - N' is a subset of N
> - E' is the subset of edges in E relating nodes in N'

(Taken from networkx inline [code comments](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/isomorphism/isomorphvf2.py).)

It defines a *mono*​morphism as the following:

> If G'=(N',E') is a monomorphism, then:
>
> - N' is a subset of N
> - E' is a subset of the set of edges in E relating nodes in N'

And further, notes:

> Note that if G' is a node-induced subgraph of G, then it is always a
>   subgraph monomorphism of G, but the opposite is not always true, as a
>   monomorphism can have fewer edges.

In other words, because there are other edges involved in this graph than are described by the `G2` graph, the `DiGraphMatcher` considers the set of edges `E'` to be *not* equal to the subset of edges in `E` relating nodes in `N'`.

Instead, the edges in `E'` are a *subset* of the set of edges in `E` relating nodes in `N'`, and so networkx calls this a *monomorphism* instead.

To better illustrate this point, consider the following:

```py
from networkx.algorithms.isomorphism import DiGraphMatcher

G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edge(1, 2)
G1.add_edge(2, 1)

G2 = nx.DiGraph()
G2.add_edge(1, 2)

print(list(DiGraphMatcher(G1, G2).subgraph_isomorphisms_iter()))
print(list(DiGraphMatcher(G1, G2).subgraph_monomorphisms_iter()))
```

This will print the following:

```py
[{1: 1, 2: 2}, {2: 1, 1: 2}] # subgraph MONOmorphism
[]                           # subgraph  ISOmorphism
```